# Sending data and saving in a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a main page with a popup window.

```
<textarea class="form-control item"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="name">Send</button>
```

There is also a second page. (/conclusion/main)

```
<textarea id="retro" style="height: 200px; width: 800px"></textarea>
```

I enter the text in the window and send. The window should close and the text should be sent to the second page and the text should be saved in the field "textarea". Even if they close the page or reload, the text should remain in the second page.
This code allows you to save, but after closing the page, does not save

```
(function(){
    var textarea = document.getElementById('retro');
    if (localStorage.retro) 
    {
        textarea.value = localStorage.retro; 
    }
    textarea.onchange = function() 
    {
        localStorage.retro = this.value; 
    }
})();
```

Sends from the first page to the second

```
function getParams(){
    var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
        var params = new Array();
        if (idx != -1) {
            var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
                for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
                    nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
                    params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
                }
        }
        return params2;
}

params = getParams();
name = unescape(params["name"]);
document.getElementById('retro').innerHTML = name;
```

Comment: You're saving the textarea text in localStorage, but on the second page you're trying to read it from the URL? All you need on the 2nd page is `document.getElementById('retro').value = localStorage.retro;`

Comment: @ChrisG 
I need the text from this pop-up window to be saved in the textarea of the second page for further text editing.

Comment: @ChrisG Code doesnt work ```document.getElementById('retro').value = localStorage.retro;```

Comment: You'll want to add `id="retro"` to the `<textarea>` on your first page.

Comment: @ChrisG I added but it didnt help

Comment: Is the script on your first page below the `<textarea>` as it has to be in order for `document.getElementById('retro');` to find it?

Comment: Yeah, you need to decide on whether you send a GET form and abuse JavaScript to grab the parameters *or* whether you use localStorage. The best way is obviously to do this server-side with PHP or the like.

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions around what you are trying to do here. What I have done is broken this down into 2 parts

1. Passing the local storage between 2 pages and accessing it.
2. Decoding Parameters in the URL and assigning them

Some assumptions that I made:

1. I have noticed some of the classes from bootstrap so i assume that you have jQuery on the page and also you may know how to use it.
2. Using chrome for testing this

**PART 1** - Passing localstorage between windows:

First thing to note is you may be better using a cookie library (js-cookie) or creating one yourself that you can access. As localstorage may well be insecure depending on what data you want to store in there.

With that out of the way, you were on the right track, just needed to add your event listener to 'input' as i think then every keystroke the data in local storage is being updated.

**Page 1**

*HTML*

```
<textarea id="retro" class="form-control item"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="name">Send</button>
```

*JS* (I would recommend place this at the bottom of you page for quick testing)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textarea = document.getElementById('retro');
    textarea.addEventListener('input',function(){
        localStorage.setItem('retro', this.value);
    })
</script>
```

In Chrome developer tools if you watch the variable 'localstorage' then you will see this change as you key in the value.

What I have done here is bound the event listener to the text area so that any 'input' the value changes, furthermore is am setting the item in the localstorage

**PAGE 2**

*HTML*

```
<textarea id="retro" style="height: 200px; width: 800px"></textarea>
```

*JS*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textarea = document.getElementById('retro').value = localStorage.getItem('retro');
</script>
```

Here using the 'getItem' method for localstorage you can then retrieve it from the storage area and output it as the value of the textarea.

Obviously is the cache or localstorage is cleared then this value will disappear.

**PART 2** - Decoding Parameters in the URL and assigning them

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}
```

This function above will get you any parameter you want form the url I found this from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/). This is using jQuery.

Here is how you would use it

```
// example.com?param1=name&param2=&id=6
$.urlParam('param1'); // name
$.urlParam('id');        // 6
$.urlParam('param2');   // null
```

Well I hope this answers your question on both parts, and helps you further, please add any comments if I have missed anything and I will be happy to update my answer

Comment: on the first page in the pop-up window, I type the text and press the send button, then it goes to the second page. How to make it so that after clicking the send button, the pop-up window closes?

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you have a button or link that opens the popup and then you want the text box and button in the popup, then for data to come back to the main screen when closing the popup?